# Flipping and replacing UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-animation

I have a `UIVIew` added as a subview in view Controller that i am trying to flip and replace it with  some other view.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.testBlueTicket toView:self.testOrangeTicket duration:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        
}];
```

The problem is that the whole viewcontroller is flipping and not just the particular view that i want to get flipped and replaced.

I have searched the documentation and have not been able to find any particular solutions. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Can you either add a video to your question telling us which view is testOrangeTicket, or post a minimum repeatable example project that we can try? (And BTW, you posted Objective-C code. You should probably not include the Swift tag for an Objective-C specific question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `[UIView transitionFromView...` animates the superview.

So, embed your `testBlueTicket` and `testOrangeTicket` views in a *container* view.

Here's a simple example:

```
@interface FlipViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *testBlueTicket;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *testOrangeTicket;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *containerView;

@end

@implementation FlipViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    
    _containerView = [UIView new];
    _testBlueTicket = [UIView new];
    _testOrangeTicket = [UIView new];
    
    _containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _testBlueTicket.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _testOrangeTicket.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    
    _containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemYellowColor];
    _testBlueTicket.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBlueColor];
    _testOrangeTicket.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemOrangeColor];
    
    // respect safe area
    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];
    
    [_containerView addSubview:_testOrangeTicket];
    [_containerView addSubview:_testBlueTicket];
    
    [self.view addSubview:_containerView];
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        [_containerView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:200.0],
        [_containerView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:260.0],
        [_containerView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.centerXAnchor],
        [_containerView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.centerYAnchor],
        
        [_testBlueTicket.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_containerView.widthAnchor multiplier:1.0],
        [_testBlueTicket.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_containerView.heightAnchor multiplier:1.0],
        [_testBlueTicket.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_containerView.centerXAnchor],
        [_testBlueTicket.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_containerView.centerYAnchor],
        
        [_testOrangeTicket.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_containerView.widthAnchor multiplier:1.0],
        [_testOrangeTicket.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_containerView.heightAnchor multiplier:1.0],
        [_testOrangeTicket.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_containerView.centerXAnchor],
        [_testOrangeTicket.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_containerView.centerYAnchor],
        
    ]];
    
    _testOrangeTicket.hidden = YES;
    
    UITapGestureRecognizer *t = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTap)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:t];
}

- (void)didTap {
    
    UIView *fromView = self.testBlueTicket.isHidden ? self.testOrangeTicket : self.testBlueTicket;
    UIView *toView = self.testBlueTicket.isHidden ? self.testBlueTicket : self.testOrangeTicket;

    [UIView transitionFromView:fromView
                        toView:toView
                      duration:2
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        
    }];
    
}

@end
```

Note that it is using `UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews` so the "ticket" views remain in the view hierarchy.

To see things more clearly, change some of the constraints on the ticket views (such as the `multiplier:` on the width and/or height constraints)... you'll then see the `.systemYellow` *container* view animating, with the ticket views embedded.